# Capybara webkit socks5 proxy support

Tags: socks, capybara-webkit

Can you provide an example of how to send all Capybara-webkit requests through socks5 proxy? Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.set_proxy method exists, but how can it be used with socks5 proxy

Answer (score 0):

Only HTTP proxies are currently supported.

In the [code to set the proxy](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/blob/master/src/SetProxy.cpp#L15), you can see that it explicitly sets an HTTP proxy unconditionally:

```
proxy = QNetworkProxy(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy,
                      arguments()[0],
                      (quint16)(arguments()[1].toInt()),
                      arguments()[2],
                      arguments()[3]);
```

Qt (the underlying library used by capybara-webkit) [does support other proxies](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkproxy.html#socks5), so you could submit a pull request to add this feature to capybara-webkit.

Comment: I've already placed an issue and the maintainer said this option should  be available in further releases

Comment: Hey Oleg - actually, I am the maintainer! I responded to a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/705) about this recently. Sorry if it was confusing, but what I meant was that I would merge a pull request to add support if you were willing to submit it. I don't use socks5 proxies, so I don't plan on adding it myself.

Comment: thanks. I understood. I'll make pull request when this option is ready.  I should complete that, once I have some time at last ;)

Comment: I've initiated pull request. There're no much modifications and they can be done some other way. Please, check